# Initialize CustomViews in CustomTableViewCell on the basis of some condition

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` and a `CustomTableViewCell`. `CustomTableViewCell` consist on two things,

1. A UIView that will be populated by other custom designed UIViews (Described below),
2. A Fixed `UIView` having some labels

Datasource of a table is some model having properties like 
`modelType = image, music, video` etc. For each model type, I have designed a `UIView`, which is to be loaded in `CustomTableViewCell`'s View on the basis of `modelType`.

My question is "How to pass dataType from `UIViewController` to `CustomTableViewCell` and then How to initialize each UIView in the basis of `modelType`".

This is what I have

```html
#import "ContentsTableViewCell.h"

@interface ContentsTableViewCell ()
@property NSString* feedType;
@end

@implementation ContentsTableViewCell

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {

// before initializing this xib I must have feedType. . . 
        NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle]    loadNibNamed:@"ContentsTableViewCell" owner:self  options:nil];
        UIView* mainView = (UIView*)[nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:mainView];    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The above code is Initializing the xib associated with this .m file. But how to pass feedType here to initialize other Views.

Comment: so you have no code? not even created a cellForRow method to pass data?

Comment: I have code, but I don't know what code portion one's needed to solve the issue.

Comment: just show what have you done to do that

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able pass any parameter in the initialisation of UITableViewCell because UITableView will dequeue or initialise it when need.

[NOTE]: Don't start implementing unless read solution 2.

**Solution 1:** You can configure this cell as you need at `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Define a enum for feed type and pass it.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FeedType)
{
    FeedTypeText,
    FeedTypeImage,
    FeedTypeAudio,
    FeedTypeVideo,
};
```

Create a method of cell configuration

```
@interface ContentsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, assign) FeedType feedType;

- (void)configureCellWithFeedType:(FeedType)feedType;

@end

@implementation ContentsTableViewCell

- (void)configureCellWithFeedType:(FeedType)feedType
{
    switch (feedType) {
        case FeedTypeText:
            // initializing  xib . .
            break;
        case FeedTypeImage:
            // initializing  xib . .
            break;
        case FeedTypeAudio:
            // initializing  xib . .
            break;
        case FeedTypeVideo:
            // initializing  xib . .
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Then call this configuration method from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
[cell configureCellWithFeedType:feedType];
```

**Solution 2** The above solution will decrease browsing performance significantly. So best way is to create four separate class with associated xib view.

```
@interface TextTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@interface ImageTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@interface AudioTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@interface VideoTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@end
```

And finally load appropriate cell as your need.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ContentsTableViewCell *cell = nil;

    FeedType feedType = FeedTypeAudio;

    switch (feedType) {
        case FeedTypeText:
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(TextTableViewCell class)];
            break;
        case FeedTypeImage:
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(ImageTableViewCell class)];
            break;
        case FeedTypeAudio:
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(AudioTableViewCell class)];
            break;
        case FeedTypeVideo:
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(VideoTableViewCell class)];
            break;
    }
  return cell;
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.